# Yocto do_install(): install utility manual

Tags: yocto, bitbake

does anybody know where to find manual for "install utility" mentioned in Yocto manual, in section describing do_install() task? Or what options are available for it? I found usage of install -d for creating a directory, or install -m for copying a file. I'd like to study more info about this tool and it's options. Thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: What have you tried? and what problems did you run into?

Comment: No problems, both cp and install -m works in our recipes, but I don't understand what's the difference and how it works. I'd like to know what are other options of install besides -d and -m and so usually I like to read the manual for better understanding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install -m is used to copy the file in root system with the given permission

man page of install will have all the required rules to install binaries in your root file system

Answer (score 5):

It's GNU install from standard linux, so 'man install'.

Comment: Very simple, It didn't came into my mind to try man install :) Thank you very much for clarification Ross.